# scale_fill in ggplot2 - Make a gradient color for every plot in a list of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I make a list of `ggplots` stored in an object called `g.a`, Here's the code to reproduce the plots (data is provided at the bottom).

Worth to note that I am probably missing something simple and over-complicated the problem.

```
RCfitter <- function(w,h,a,b){(a * ((w + h)^b))}

fillfactor <- lapply(seq_len(length(dat.a)), function(i) {
              as.factor((gsub("-.*","",dat.a[[i]]$Date)))}) #I tried as.integer as well

set.seed(92)
lin.a <- lapply(seq_len(length(dat.a)), function(i) {
                          data.frame(x = runif(100, -dB.coef.a[3,i],
                          max(dat.a[[i]]$WL)+diff(0.2*range(dat.a[[i]]$Q))))})

library(ggplot2)

g.a <- lapply(seq_len(length(dat.a)), function(i) {
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dat.a[[i]], aes(x=WL,y=Q, tltip = Date,
fill =fillfactor[[i]]),
colour = NA, pch=21) + 

scale_fill_manual(breaks = mybreaks, values = myfills)+

geom_line(data = lin.a[[i]], 
          aes(x=x,y= RCfitter(x,dB.coef.a[3,i],dB.coef.a[1,i],dB.coef.a[2,i])),colour="red")+

xlab("WL") +
ylab("Q") +
ggtitle(paste("pLot ",i)) +
ylim(c(0,(max(dat.a[[i]]$Q)+diff(0.2*range(dat.a[[i]]$Q))))) +
xlim(c(0,(max(dat.a[[i]]$WL)+diff(0.2*range(dat.a[[i]]$WL))))) +
theme(legend.position="none")
                              })
```

If I ignore the `scale_fill` I can plot them and I will get the "colorful" plot. But with that I get this warning:

```
g.a[[2]]

##  Warning messages:
##  1: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
##  2: Removed 64 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Which means `geom_point` does not plot anything.

I used `scale_fill_discrete`, `scale_fill_continuous`, etc. and they give me errors like `discrete value to continuous scale` or vice versa or.

**What I really want** is to make a **gradient color for years**, let's say from blue to red, so I can distinguish between the years while seeing if there's a chunk of similar years (e.g. 60s) around the same spot.

P.S. At the end, I am using `ggplotly()` (e.g. `ggplotly(g.a[[2]],tooltip = c("x","y","tltip")`). So, if that would change the behavior of `scale_fill` (which is, for example, some of the colors that I have specified are invalid for `plotly`) , please have that in mind.

## Sample Data:

`dat.a`

```
 dat.a <- list(structure(list(Date = c("1974-02-14", "1974-02-16", "1974-02-28",
     "1974-02-28", "1974-02-28", "1974-02-28"), WL = c(0.24, 0.135, 
     0.395, 0.26, 0.22, 0.31), Q = c(0.237, 0.04, 0.9, 0.36, 0.52,           
     0.56), Velocity = c(0.3, 0.103, 0.367, 0.209, 0.34, 0.276), Area = c(0.79, 
     0.388, 2.452, 1.722, 1.529, 2.029), Flag = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
     NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
         Shift = c("/", "/", "/", "/", "/", "/"), date = structure(c(130032000,  
         130204800, 131241600, 131241600, 131241600, 131241600), class = c("POSIXct",  
         "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("Date", "WL", "Q",  
     "Velocity", "Area", "Flag", "Shift", "date"), row.names = c(NA, 
     -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(          
         Date = c("1965-01-29", "1965-01-29", "1965-04-25", "1966-11-29",   
         "1967-01-24", "1967-11-12"), WL = c(0.439, 0.439, 0.482,     
         0.463, 0.427, 0.475), Q = c(0.252, 0.269, 0.403, 0.314, 0.199,
         0.4), Velocity = c(0.23, 0.232, 0.316, 0.279, 0.249, 0.36      
         ), Area = c(1.096, 1.159, 1.275, 1.125, 0.799, 1.111), Flag = c(NA_character_,  
         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,                   
         NA_character_), Shift = c("/", "/", "/", "/", "/", "/"),                      
         date = structure(c(-155347200, -155347200, -147916800, -97545600,    
         -92707200, -67478400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
        .Names = c("Date","WL", "Q", "Velocity", "Area", "Flag", "Shift", "date"), 
        row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

`dB.coef.a`

```
 dB.coef.a <- structure(c(-77.6915945552795, 0.594614568300253, 60.9718752625543, 
     7.96297849987566, 2.69599957356069, -0.183937755444007), .Dim = c(3L,        
     2L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "h"), NULL))
```

`mybreaks`

```
 mybreaks <- c(1955, 1956, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 
     1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977,     
     1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988,     
     1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999,     
     2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010,     
     2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017)
```

`myfills`

```
 myfills <- c("005ABF", "0358BC", "0757B9", "0A56B6", "0E54B3", "1153B0",  
     "1552AD", "1851AA", "1C4FA7", "1F4EA4", "234DA2", "264B9F", "2A4A9C", 
     "2D4999", "314896", "344693", "384590", "3B448D", "3F428A", "424187", 
     "464085", "493F82", "4D3D7F", "503C7C", "543B79", "573976", "5B3873", 
     "5E3770", "62366D", "65346A", "693368", "6D3265", "703062", "742F5F", 
     "772E5C", "7B2D59", "7E2B56", "822A53", "852950", "89274D", "8C264B", 
     "902548", "932445", "972242", "9A213F", "9E203C", "A11E39", "A51D36", 
     "A81C33", "AC1B30", "AF192E", "B3182B", "B61728", "BA1525", "BD1422", 
     "C1131F", "C4121C", "C81019", "CB0F16", "CF0E13", "D30D11")
```

Comment: Your code is quite difficult to read. Can you define the function that generates the plots outside the `lapply` statement and format nicely? Also, it generally helps for readability if you first add all the geoms, then the scales, then the rest.

Comment: @ClausWilke Simplified it by making it less dense (visually) and bringing the parameter outside of the loop, so you can see each part clearer and separated from each other. Note that this is an already shortened and the actual code has much more to offer. Meanwhile, the simplified version does reproduce the error for me so we should be good for solving that matter.

Comment: @Masoud : Is there a reason to use `pch = 21` and `color = F` for `geom_point` ? Why not use directly use `pch = 16` and use `color` instead of `fill` ?

Comment: @bVa that tended to mess up with the color of the `geom_line()`. As I have been browsing through the threads, I found this suggestion for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion, if I correctly understood your problem : 


**1.** I have an error message with colors (`myfills`) :

> Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE)

`#` is missing :

```
mycolors <- paste0("#", myfills) # correct colors
names(mycolors ) <- mybreaks # name your colors
mycolors[names(mycolors) == "1965"] <- "#D30D11" # swapped color to red to check its ok
```

**2.** If you really want no "color" with `pch = 21` for `geom_point`, better use `pch = 16`, then forget `fill` aesthetics and use `color` instead :

```
g.a <- lapply(seq_len(length(dat.a)), function(i) {
    ggplot(data = dat.a[[i]], aes(x = WL, y = Q, color = fillfactor[[i]])) + 
    geom_point(pch = 16) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = mycolors) +
    geom_line(data = lin.a[[i]], aes(x = x, y = RCfitter(x, dB.coef.a[3,i], dB.coef.a[1,i], dB.coef.a[2,i])), colour = "red") +
    ggtitle(paste("pLot ",i)) +
    ylim(c(0,(max(dat.a[[i]]$Q) + diff(0.2*range(dat.a[[i]]$Q))))) +
    xlim(c(0,(max(dat.a[[i]]$WL) + diff(0.2*range(dat.a[[i]]$WL))))) +
    theme(legend.position="none")
 }
)
g.a[[2]]
```

[image]

**3.** Warning message about `geom_path` is due to your `xlim()`.

Comment: On the actual dataset and more elaborated code I had tweak around some other parts to get this to work but at the end I was able to resolve the issue with your suggestion. Cheers.